# Any .Net reporting tool that can display images or tables embedded in RTF or HTML?

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, crystal-reports, rtf

My problem is I currently have a Winforms RichTextBox (RTB) which can contain formatted text, images and tables. Reading it back from the database works as desired. However, trying to print what's in that RTB (among other related fields as well) onto a report doesn't. It seems from everything I've found so far that both MS Report Viewer and Crystal Reports don't support any image or table tags contained within Rich Text Format (RTF) or HTML. Even third-party tools like those from Telerik won't support it. The only potential workaround seems to be converting that RTB to an image. Not sure how well that would work print quality wise or the fact that the RTB could contain several printed pages worth of content.

The only practical solution I can think of is parsing out the non-supported tags and creating the RDL needed for the image or table dynamically. Any other alternatives or suggestions?

Comment: I'm having problems converting rtf to html where the rtf text contains html tables. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder No, I haven't found one yet. Shocks me that something that should be fairly common is such a pain.